# Can a roof be supported with a 2x12 which is cantaleverd 8'?

Tags: wood, construction, load

I'm building a 12x24 building with 8' of the roof 10psf. being supported with one 2x12 on each side cantaleverd 8'from the other 16' of the building. Will a single 2x12 on either side of the 8 x 12 roof support the roof being cantaleverd?

Comment: So you're building a 12x16 building with a roof that cantilevers 8'-0" beyond the exterior wall? "Cantilever" means a diving-board-like structure without any support at its tip. This is what you have in mind? No posts at the tip? And this 10psf? This is a dead load? Live load? Snow load?

Comment: Please post a plan, a hand drawn one is fine

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the uncantilevered length...

Answer (score 2):

The International Residential Code (IRC) that governs most residential construction in the US provides for short cantilevers in some situations. 8'-0" cantilevered from a 16'-0" is way out of bounds for IRC tables. You would need an engineer to size beams for this cantilever.